# Reducible polynomial among sequence of polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, finite-fields

Let $a_1$ and $a_2$ be two elements of a finte field $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$ of even characteristic and $a_1^2\neq a_2$. Is it true that there always exists an element $a\in\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_{2^m}|a_{k+2}=a_1\cdot a_{k+1}+a_{k},k=1,2,\ldots\,2^m-2\}$ such that the polynomial $x^2+ax+1$ is reducible over $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$?

Any help or comment is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried calculating $a_4$ and $a_5$?

Comment: Yes, I tried. My computer calculations show that for $GF(2^5)$ it will be enough $\{a_1,\ldots,a_7\}$ elements, but not less. If field is growing then the number of elements that you need to take is also growing.

Comment: If that's true, then you have made a typo in the problem; as currently written, $a_4 = a_3 + a_2 = (a_2 + a_1) + a_2 = a_1$. I suspect the recurrence relation should be $a_{k + 2} = a_{k + 1} + a_k^2$.

Comment: Yes, I've made a typo, thanks. It should be $a_{k+2}=a_1\cdot a_{k+1}+a_k$.

Comment: In computer calculations is there any apparent relationship between the order of $a$ in the multiplicative group and the reducibility of $x^2+ax+1$?

Comment: I did not notice any relationship between the order of $a$ and the reducibility of $x^2+ax+1$.